# Как быстро удалить элементы из TreeView (с группировкой) и без Collapse его элементов

Tags: wpf

Есть коллекция nodes типа - ObservableCollection<Node> для отображения в TreeView с группировкой по свойству Type.

```
 public class Node
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public NodeType Type { get; set; }
 } 

//... 

ListCollectionView nodesView = new ListCollectionView(nodes);
nodesView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Type"));

ListCollectionView groupedView = new ListCollectionView(nodesView.Groups);
GroupedNodesTreeView.ItemsSource = groupedView;
```

Удаление сразу нескольких найденных (searched) элементов из nodes следующим образом

```
foreach (Node node in searched)
{
   nodes.Remove(node);
}
```

происходит медленно.

Каким образом можно быстро удалить элементы из TreeView?
При этом можно ли сделать так, чтобы TreeView не меняло свойство IsExpanded элементов (т.е. после удаления не "сворачивало" их).

(Если заменить ObservableCollection на BatchingObservableCollection,
где при завершении удаления происходит NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset, то TreeView все же "сворачивает" (Collapse) элементы. Происходит обновление всего TreeView)

Comment: Для начала, стоит указывать все необходимые метки у вопроса, как минимум, вы так больше получите просмотров) По поводу вопроса - зачем вам тут `ListCollectionView` и почему не используются нормальные привязки? Далее, почему `TreeView`, если у вас нету "древовидности"? Обычно, при использование `TreeView` делают класс, который содержит в себе заголовок и коллекцию этого-же класса, а у вас просто нода с именем и типом... На вашем месте, я бы отказался от `ListCollectionView`, сделал коллекцию групп, в которых была бы коллекция самих объектов и все это привязал.

Comment: А по поводу "Медленно" - что именно? Удаление из коллекции, или обновление UI? И сколько же у вас там объектов, что "медленно"? И зачем вы удаляете, может тогда просто скрыть? Вон ставьте `ListCollectionView` фильтр и отображайте нужное. А по поводу "сворачивает" - попробуйте привязать свойство. Пусть допустим ваш класс `Node` содержит в себе `public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }` и пусть уже это свойство решает раскрывать объект или нет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо. "медленно" - т.е. обновление UI из-за типа ObservableCollection<Node>, т.к. из List<Node> они удаляются быстрее 
(недостаток в том, что дерево приходится полностью обновлять и оно будет "сворачивать" элементы.) 
Элементов было 60 тыс., сгруппированных в 2 группы, а удалить сразу нужно было 40 тыс.).
Тогда по вашему совету откажусь от ListCollectionView и сделаю коллекцию групп.